# Dynamically adding items to Xamarin CarouselPage not working in IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, carousel

I have a project that is deployable to Android and IOS. In the common project, I have a CarouselPage. I have a ProductPage that is dynamically added x times to the CarouselPage to facilitate the display of items in a category. The image item on the ProductPage is a hyperlink reference (h ttp://www.xxx.com/image/yyy.png for example). Selecting the category opens a page with a ListView, and the person can scroll through and select a product, which the opens the CarouselPage and populates it, making the product selected in the ListView the current item being viewed. The person can then scroll back/forth through the carousel to view the detail page for each item in the category.

Right now there is a draggable item on the product detail page and moving it attempts to scroll the carousel, so I have changed the code so only one item at a time is actually loaded into the CarouselPage until I resolve this issue. There are previous/next buttons on the product page to facilitate scrolling through the catalog since the swipe action is temporarily disabled.

Here is the code to populate the product view that is added to the carousel.

```
            carPages = new List<ProductPage>();

            foreach (cwImage image in selectedCategory.cwImages)
            {
                pageCount++;
                var newContentPage = new ProductPage();

                //This converts the image name to a hyperlink
                var imgSource = string.Concat(cwSettings.CategoryData.BaseUrl, image.ImageUrl);
                newContentPage.pageNumber = pageCount;

                //Set the image source to the hyperlink
                newContentPage.WrapImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(imgSource));
                newContentPage._textColor = (Color)(converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(image.DefaultColor));

                //Add to list
                carPages.Add(newContentPage);

                var selectedImage = imageUrl.ToString().Replace("Uri: " + cwSettings.CategoryData.BaseUrl, "");
                if (image.ImageUrl == selectedImage)
                {
                    //Make this page the current page
                    Children.Add(newContentPage);
                    CurrentPage = (ContentPage)newContentPage;
                }

            }
```

Bottom line is this works like MAGIC on Android, but the CarouselPage always comes up blank on IOS and I cannot figure out why. The code is executed as expected and the IOS previewer shows the page properly. I tried substituting a dumb page instead of the ProductPage, same result; it shows in the IOS previewer but does not display in the app. The ProductPage is of type ContentPage.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since it works in Android with same code and through your description, I think the problem in iOS is that the image does not load properly.

So, check the [App Transport Security in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats).

Add following key-values to info.plist to completely disable ATS for all domains and internet otherwise it will block the web link start with `http`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Did not work. Even when I remove the image from the ProductPage View, the page does not display.

Comment: Do you mean the page has not been added to the CarouselPage? Can you add a breakpoint there to check if the code executed?

Comment: The code is executing. I restructured the logic. It still works in Android, now I am getting this error in IOS the second time I attempt to open the carouselPage. DetailPage is the carousel, ProductPage is the instance being added to the CarouselPage as children. The code is fairly close to what is above and both are in the same namespace.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'CurbWrap.Catalog.ProductPage' was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: This error usually happens when the ProductPage is not exist or not been initialized. I need see more code to find out the cause.

Comment: I rewrote the page to not use the carousel. I think this is an iOS bug felt I do not have the time to be able to spend, deadlines are tight.

Comment: If you can provide us a sample, I will look into it and you can report an issue on Github once you have time.